# eledmac/eledpar having one footnote series per \pstart...\pend

Tags: footnotes, eledmac, eledpar

I'm using `eledmac`/`eledpar` for a critical edition. 
I am using paragraphed critical footnotes.

I need the footnotes of each `\pstart ... \pend` to be printed in a separate block (separated with a line from the other footnotes). This can be achieved by using one footnote series for each `\pstart ... \pend` like here:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lipsum,eledmac,eledpar}

\numberonlyfirstinline 
\footparagraph{A} 
\footparagraph{B} 

\txtbeforeXnotes[A]{Footnotes of first paragraph:~~}
\txtbeforeXnotes[B]{Footnotes of second paragraph:~~}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering

    \pstart
    \edtext{Here}{\Afootnote{First footnote in A}} is the 
    \edtext{first}{\Afootnote{Second footnote in A.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[1]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{Here}{\Bfootnote{First footnote in A}} is the 
    \edtext{second}{\Bfootnote{Second footnote in A.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2]
    \pend

    % Many more \pstart ... \pend to follow. 

    \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart Test \pend
    \pstart Test \pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Rightside}

\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, my text has very many paragraphs and it seems I cannot define a new footnote series for each of them. Is there any trick to print one footnote register at `\pend`, to "clear" it out and to reset the `\txtbeforeXnotes`?

Or is there any other means to have one block of footnotes per `\pstart ... \pend` structure without defining very many footnote series?

I was thinking of defining e.g. 5 footnote series `A ... E` and then using them in a circular order. But the problem is on the page where `\footnoteE` is succeeded by `\footnoteA` that the notes of series `A` will be printed above series `E`, contrary to the order of the corresponding paragraphs.

Comment: now, the solution I have proposed works for both eledmac and eledpar. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

**For eledmac**

Some one ask me for this many year ago.  I don't find the answer I made. I think the circular way is the best.

There is still the problem of  the series position of the pstart which starts in a page and continue in a other page. Use `seriesatend` to solve this problem: it make the current series be positionned at the end of all series, and not at the eledmac initial position.

This MWE works with eledmac. It can't work with parallel text, because of the way \AtEveryPstart work.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lipsum,eledmac,eledpar}

\numberonlyfirstinline 
\footparagraph{A} 
\footparagraph{B} 
\footparagraph{C}
\footparagraph{D}
\footparagraph{E}   

    % Here, the loop system
  \newcounter{mynotelevel}%
    \renewcommand{\themynotelevel}{\Alph{mynotelevel}}% For the list


  \AtEveryPstart{%
        \addtocounter{mynotelevel}{1}%Step counter
        \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevel}}{6}{%
          \setcounter{mynotelevel}{1}%
        }{}%
          \global\letcs{\mynote}{\themynotelevel footnote}%  %
          \seriesatend{\themynotelevel}%
  }
\begin{document}

    \beginnumbering

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel first}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[1]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

        \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend
        \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2]\edtext{on therpage}{\mynote{on otherpage}} 
    \pend

        \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend
    % Many more \pstart ... \pend to follow. 

    \endnumbering

\end{document}
```

**For eledpar**

When typesetting parallel pstart, the `AtEveryPstart` is called WHEN the pstart is effectivly printed (so `\Pages`) and not when the `\pstart` is called. That is perfect for the `\seriesatend` but not for the `\global\letcs{\mynote}{\themynotelevel footnote}`, because the footnote are processed  when `\pstart...\pend` is read by LaTeX.

The solution will be to add a new `AtEveryPstartCall`, called not in `\Pages` but in `\pstart`.  I have made it in the new version 1.15.0 of eledpar (in the CTAN)

There is stil the problem of the alternate between left and right notes. The best way is to use A,B,C,D,E for left and F,G,H,I,J for right.

So the example become

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[series={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}]{eledmac}%Declare series to use
\usepackage{eledpar}

\numberonlyfirstinline 
% Series as paragraph
\footparagraph{A}%For Left (1)
\footparagraph{B}%For left (2)
\footparagraph{C}%For left (3)
\footparagraph{D}%For left (4)
\footparagraph{E}%For left (5)
\footparagraph{F}%For right (6) 
\footparagraph{G}%For right (7) 
\footparagraph{H}%For right (8) 
\footparagraph{I}%For right (9) 
\footparagraph{J}%For right (10) 

    % Here, the loop system
\makeatletter% We need to use command with @
  % Two counters: one for left and one for right
  \newcounter{mynotelevel}%
    \renewcommand{\themynotelevel}{\Alph{mynotelevel}}% Print the counter as a letter
  \newcounter{mynotelevelR}%
    \renewcommand{\themynotelevelR}{\Alph{mynotelevelR}}% Print the counter as a letter
  \setcounter{mynotelevelR}{5}

  % Following lines are called at each \pstart
  \AtEveryPstartCall{%
        \ifledRcol%If it's a right pstart
          \addtocounter{mynotelevelR}{1}%Step counter
          \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevelR}}{11}{%Not more than J series (10)
            \setcounter{mynotelevelR}{6}% If more than J => restart to F (6)
          }{}%
            \global\letcs{\mynote}{\themynotelevelR footnote}%  And let mynote equal to <X>footnote, where <X> is the current level \letcs is defined by etoolbox, called by eledmac        
        \else% If it's a left page
          \addtocounter{mynotelevel}{1}%Step counter
          \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevel}}{6}{%Not more than E series (5)
            \setcounter{mynotelevel}{1}%If more than J => restart to A (1)
          }{}%
            \global\letcs{\mynote}{\themynotelevel footnote}%And let mynote equal to <X>footnote, where <X> is the current level \letcs is defined by etoolbox, called by eledmac        

                \fi%
  }
  % This code is called when begins of  pstart are printed
  \AtEveryPstart{%
    \ifodd\c@page%If we are on a left page
        \addtocounter{mynotelevelR}{1}%Step counter
        \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevelR}}{11}{%Not more than J series (10)
          \setcounter{mynotelevelR}{6}}{}% If more than J => restart to F (6)
                    \seriesatend{\themynotelevelR}% The series should be at the end
            \else
        \addtocounter{mynotelevel}{1}%Step counter
        \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevel}}{6}{%Not more than E series (5)
          \setcounter{mynotelevel}{1}}{}%% If more than E => restart to A (1)
          \seriesatend{\themynotelevel}% The series should be at the end
    \fi
   }

\makeatother
\begin{document}




\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering


    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel first}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[1]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

        \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend
        \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2]\edtext{on therpage}{\mynote{on otherpage}} 
    \pend

        \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend


    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel first}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[1]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

        \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend
        \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2]\edtext{on therpage}{\mynote{on otherpage}} 
    \pend

        \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend
    % Many more \pstart ... \pend to follow. 

    \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR first}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[1]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

        \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend
        \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2]\edtext{on therpage}{\mynote{on otherpage}} 
    \pend

        \pstart sss\themynotelevelR
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR first}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[1]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

        \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend
        \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2]\edtext{on therpage}{\mynote{on otherpage}} 
    \pend

        \pstart sss\themynotelevelR
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    % Many more \pstart ... \pend to follow. 

    \endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\setcounter{mynotelevel}{0}%Restart the left counter
\setcounter{mynotelevelR}{5}% And restart the right counter
\Pages
\end{pages}

\end{document}
```

**Final remarks**

More series you use, more eledmac will be slow. If you use only critical footnotes (Xfootnote) and not familiar  (\footnoteX), I could maybe add one option to help to have a faster eledmac. I also think I should add option to disable the managing of ledgroup/minipage with eledmac (will be faster).

I think I could also optimizate series atend

Comment: I have edited to a better and simpler answer.

Comment: Hi Maieul, thank you so much for your excellent answer. This was very helpful. I have the remaining problem that the ordering of the series doesn't work well. If I add the `\seriesatend{\themynotelevel}` command in your `eledpar` version of the answer, the notes on the last page are sorted correctly, but the notes on all previous pages not. This is because typesetting of notes seems to be done at the point of the `\Pages` command and then the *final* sorting of `\@series` is applied on all pages. I'm working on this and I will post here again when I have a solution :)

Comment: hum, that strange. Ad implementator of \AtEveryPstart I can say you that its content is called when the pstart is printed. I think the problem is in other place. But for now I don't find where.

Comment: the problem is with the implementation of \ifledRcol@.

Comment: Ok, I have posted new example which work. There was still some problem, but now it should be solved. In my example, I have added some lines to check the value of the counter/order of the series. Now it's ok.

Comment: Yes it seems to work, thanks! Now I'll try to understand what you did :)

Comment: I have add comment to code and deleted line. I will add some finl remarks.

Comment: Aaaaaaah, ok, so we have to do the whole circular arithmetics of counters *twice*, one time when `\pstart` is called, and one time when `\pstart` is printed. This is kind of the clue as it seems.

Comment: Ah, and yes, adding an option to disable the minipage functionality to speed up eledmac would be cool. At least I'm not using minipages.

Comment: that is the clue ;-)

Comment: the gain of speed won't be soo much with this option. The best speed will be for disabling critical or familiar notes. It is in my todo list

Comment: OK, tank you again for this great work. As a final step I also added the possibility to have a new txtbeforeXnotes for each of the `\pstart...\pend` (which was part of my original problem). See my separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the excellent answer by Maïeul:

I also need an individual `\txtbeforeXnotes` for each of the `\pstart...\pend` (to be able to provide local source information). To enable this, I added counters `parcount` and `parcountR` which get increased appropriately in `\AtEveryPstart` and `\AtEveryPstartCall` to get a unique number for each `\pstart...\pend`. Then there is a macro

```
\def\thispartxtbeforenotes#1{%
    \csgdef{txtbefore@par@\theparcount}{#1}
}%
```

which can be called from within the `\pstart...\pend` to store the individual prefix text. Finally, in `\AtEveryPstart`, which is the macro that is called when the `\pstart...\pend` is actually *printed*, I added

```
\exp_args:Nnf \csgdef{txtbeforeXnotes@\themynotelevel}{\csuse{txtbefore@par@\theparcount}:\quad}%
```

to take the previously stored txtbeforenotes as the current txtbeforenotes.

Here is the full MWE with this feature added (for left notes only but can be easily copy-pasted for right notes):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[series={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}]{ledmacIssue260/eledmac}
\usepackage{ledmacIssue260/eledpar}

\numberonlyfirstinline 
\footparagraph{A} 
\footparagraph{B} 
\footparagraph{C}
\footparagraph{D}
\footparagraph{E}
\footparagraph{F} 
\footparagraph{G} 
\footparagraph{H}
\footparagraph{I}
\footparagraph{J}     

\makeatletter
  % New counters to count the left/right instances of \pstart 
  \newcounter{parcount}
  \newcounter{parcountR}

  \newcounter{mynotelevel}%
  \renewcommand{\themynotelevel}{\Alph{mynotelevel}}% For the list

  \newcounter{mynotelevelR}%
  \renewcommand{\themynotelevelR}{\Alph{mynotelevelR}}% For the list

  \setcounter{mynotelevelR}{5}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% This is used when \pstart is called: 
\AtEveryPstartCall{%
    (PstartCall thepage:\thepage Pstart:\thepstartL parcount:\theparcount) %

    \ifledRcol%
      \addtocounter{parcountR}{1}% 
      \addtocounter{mynotelevelR}{1}%
      \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevelR}}{11}{%
        \setcounter{mynotelevelR}{6}%
      }{}%
        \global\letcs{\mynote}{\themynotelevelR footnote}%  %          
    \else
      \addtocounter{parcount}{1}% 
      \addtocounter{mynotelevel}{1}%
      \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevel}}{6}{%
        \setcounter{mynotelevel}{1}%
      }{}%
        \global\letcs{\mynote}{\themynotelevel footnote}%  %
    \fi%
  }

% This is used when the \pstart is printed: 
\AtEveryPstart{%
    (PstartStart thepage:\thepage Pstart:\thepstartL parcount:\theparcount.)

    \ifodd\c@page   
        \addtocounter{parcountR}{1}%
    \addtocounter{mynotelevelR}{1}%
    \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevelR}}{11}{%
      \setcounter{mynotelevelR}{6}}{}%
            \seriesatend{\themynotelevelR}%
    \else
        \addtocounter{parcount}{1}%
    \addtocounter{mynotelevel}{1}%
    \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevel}}{6}{%
      \setcounter{mynotelevel}{1}}{}%
      \seriesatend{\themynotelevel}%
    \ifcsdef{txtbefore@par@\theparcount}{%
           \exp_args:Nnf \csgdef{txtbeforeXnotes@\themynotelevel}{\csuse{txtbefore@par@\theparcount}:\quad}%
    }{%
       \csgdef{txtbeforeXnotes@\themynotelevel}{}%
    }
    \fi
   }

\def\thispartxtbeforenotes#1{%
    \csgdef{txtbefore@par@\theparcount}{#1}
}%

\ExplSyntaxOff 


\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering

    \pstart
        \thispartxtbeforenotes{Source 1}
        \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
        \edtext{\themynotelevel first}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
        \lipsum[1]
    \pend

    \pstart
        \thispartxtbeforenotes{Source 2}
        \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
        \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
        \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart
        \thispartxtbeforenotes{Source 3}
        \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
        \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
        \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart
        \thispartxtbeforenotes{Source 4}
        \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
        \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
        \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart
        \thispartxtbeforenotes{Source 5}
        \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
        \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
        \lipsum[2]\edtext{on therpage}{\mynote{on otherpage}} 
    \pend

    \pstart
        \thispartxtbeforenotes{Source 6}
        \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
        \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
        \lipsum[2] 
    \pend


    \pstart
        \thispartxtbeforenotes{Source 7}
        \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
        \edtext{\themynotelevel first}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
        \lipsum[1]
    \pend

    \pstart
        \thispartxtbeforenotes{Source 8}
        \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
        \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
        \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart
        \thispartxtbeforenotes{Source 9}
        \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
        \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
        \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart
        \thispartxtbeforenotes{Source 10}
        \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
        \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
        \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart
        \thispartxtbeforenotes{Source 11}
        \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
        \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
        \lipsum[2]\edtext{on therpage}{\mynote{on otherpage}} 
    \pend

    \pstart
        \thispartxtbeforenotes{Source 12}
        \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
        \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
        \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR first}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend
    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart sss\themynotelevelR
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR first}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend
    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart sss\themynotelevelR
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \endnumbering
\end{Rightside}

% Counters have to be resetted to 0 here as the circular arithmetics of 
% has to start again when \Pages is called:
\setcounter{parcount}{0}
\setcounter{mynotelevel}{0}
\setcounter{mynotelevelR}{5}
\Pages
\end{pages}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** The optional argument of `\pstart[]` is executed when the `\pstart` is *printed* (not called). This can be used to simplify the implementation according to Maïeul's comment. Counting the paragraphs and saving the txtbeforenotes for each of them under a separate csname is therefore not necessary. Here is a simplified MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[series={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}]{ledmacIssue260/eledmac}
\usepackage{ledmacIssue260/eledpar}

\numberonlyfirstinline 
\footparagraph{A} 
\footparagraph{B} 
\footparagraph{C}
\footparagraph{D}
\footparagraph{E}
\footparagraph{F} 
\footparagraph{G} 
\footparagraph{H}
\footparagraph{I}
\footparagraph{J}     

\makeatletter
  \newcounter{mynotelevel}%
  \renewcommand{\themynotelevel}{\Alph{mynotelevel}}% 

  \newcounter{mynotelevelR}%
  \renewcommand{\themynotelevelR}{\Alph{mynotelevelR}}% 

  \setcounter{mynotelevelR}{5}

% This is used when \pstart is called: 
\AtEveryPstartCall{%
    (PstartCall thepage:\thepage Pstart:\thepstartL ) %

    \ifledRcol%
      \addtocounter{mynotelevelR}{1}%
      \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevelR}}{11}{%
    \setcounter{mynotelevelR}{6}%
      }{}%
    \global\letcs{\mynote}{\themynotelevelR footnote}%  %          
    \else
      \addtocounter{mynotelevel}{1}%
      \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevel}}{6}{%
    \setcounter{mynotelevel}{1}%
      }{}%
    \global\letcs{\mynote}{\themynotelevel footnote}%  %
    \fi%
  }

% This is used when the \pstart is printed: 
\AtEveryPstart{%
    \@rotatecounters%
    \csgdef{txtbeforeXnotes@\themynotelevel}{}%
}
\def\@rotatecounters{%
    (PstartStart thepage:\thepage Pstart:\thepstartL.)
  \ifodd\c@page
    \addtocounter{mynotelevelR}{1}%
    \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevelR}}{11}{%
      \setcounter{mynotelevelR}{6}}{}%
        \seriesatend{\themynotelevelR}%
  \else
    \addtocounter{mynotelevel}{1}%
    \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevel}}{6}{%
      \setcounter{mynotelevel}{1}}{}%
      \seriesatend{\themynotelevel}%
  \fi
}

% This can be provided in the optional argument of \pstart. The optional
% argument of pstart will replace the \AtEveryPstart, so it will be executed
% when the \pstart is printed (not called). 
\def\thispartxtbeforeXnotes#1{%
    \@rotatecounters%
    \ifodd\c@page   
    \else
          \csgdef{txtbeforeXnotes@\themynotelevel}{#1\quad}%
    \fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering

    \pstart[\thispartxtbeforeXnotes{Source 1}]
%   \thispartxtbeforenotes{Source 1}
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel first}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[1]
    \pend

    \pstart[\thispartxtbeforeXnotes{Source 2}]
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart[\thispartxtbeforeXnotes{Source 3}]
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart[\thispartxtbeforeXnotes{Source 4}]
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart[\thispartxtbeforeXnotes{Source 5}]
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2]\edtext{on therpage}{\mynote{on otherpage}} 
    \pend

    \pstart[\thispartxtbeforeXnotes{Source 6}]
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend


    \pstart[\thispartxtbeforeXnotes{Source 7}]
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel first}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[1]
    \pend

    \pstart[\thispartxtbeforeXnotes{Source 8}]
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart[\thispartxtbeforeXnotes{Source 9}]
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart[\thispartxtbeforeXnotes{Source 10}]
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \pstart[\thispartxtbeforeXnotes{Source 11}]
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2]\edtext{on therpage}{\mynote{on otherpage}} 
    \pend

    \pstart[\thispartxtbeforeXnotes{Source 11}]
    \edtext{\themynotelevel Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevel}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevel second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevel.}} paragraph: 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \pend

    \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR first}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend
    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart sss\themynotelevelR
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR first}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend
    \pstart
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \pstart sss\themynotelevelR
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR Here}{\mynote{First footnote in \themynotelevelR}} is the 
    \edtext{\themynotelevelR second}{\mynote{Second footnote in \themynotelevelR.}} paragraph: 
    \pend

    \endnumbering
\end{Rightside}

% Counters have to be resetted to 0 here as the circular arithmetics of 
% has to start again when \Pages is called:
\setcounter{mynotelevel}{0}
\setcounter{mynotelevelR}{5}
\Pages
\end{pages}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a simpler way. All pstart can have an optional argument (in bracket) which is called in place of the arguments of \AtEveryPstart. So You could do something like `\pstart[\thispstartsetting{Text}]`.

Comment: In `\thispstartsetting` definition you do two thing : 1) setting the counter of mynotelevel and use seriesatend (as in my answer) 2) call `\txtbeforeXnotes[\themynotelevel]{#1}`

Comment: Right. I edited my answer.

Comment: don't forget to use \makeatother and \ExplSyntaxOff after your command definition

Comment: you should not do ` \csgdef{txtbeforeXnotes@\themynotelevel}{#1\quad}%` but do `\txtbeforeXnotes[\themynotelevel]{#1\quad}`. Actually, indeed, that is the same. But it is not sure that it will in the future. Commands with @ are for package private use. Not for public use.